# JQuery.submit(function(event){}) and JQuery.Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am having really hard time understanding how to do jquery ajax call in jquery submit() and submit the form if certain conditions returned true from the server in the ajax call, **or** if there is some error or the returned data contains errorcode then stop the form from being submitted, **without making the ajax call synchronous.**

What is troubling me is where should I `return true;` to submit the form and where should I `return false;` to stop the form from being submitted.

Here is what I have tried till now, everything is working except the form is not being submitted.

*Please read on*

```
$( '#sign_up' ).submit( function ( event ) {

    if ( $ ( '#somthing' ).val (  ) ) { return true; }

    var scriptUrl = $ ( '#upload_url' ).val (  );
    var data = new FormData (  );

    data.append ( 'otherstuff', 'something' ); 

    $returnvalue = false;

    $.ajax ( {
        method : 'POST', url : scriptUrl, data : data, cache : false, processData: false, contentType: false, dataType : 'json',
        success : function ( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) 
        { 
            // the data.error is not defined so the backend was successful
            if ( typeof data.error === 'undefined' )
            { 
                $returnvalue = true; 
            }
            // something was wrong at the backend
            else 
            {
                ( "#ajax_error" ).html ( data.message );
                $( '#upload' ).html ( 'upload File' );       
                $returnvalue = false;
            }

        },
        /*
         * Error conecting to the php file, Ajax function failed
         * This event is only called if an error occurred with the request (you can never have both an error and a success callback with a request)
         */
        error : function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) 
        {
            $returnvalue = false;

        },
        complete : function ( jqXHR,  textStatus )
        {
            if ( textStatus.localeCompare ( 'success' ) === 0 )
            {
                return true;// this should submit the form but it isn't
            }

        }
    } );

    return $returnvalue;

});
```

Comment: You can't return from async functions like that...

Comment: For starters you can never return a value from inside a callback to the outer function. If you traced the code line by line you will see that the function exits long before the Ajax callbacks fire. *"You are ordering pizza then trying to eat it before it is delivered!"*

Comment: @tymeJV Yes, I understand that, I am looking for solution

Comment: I suggest stopping the default submission with [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) and then programmatically submitting the form with [submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) when necessary.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie exactly, but what the solution is ?

Comment: busy typing (if you will let me) :)

Comment: @showdev: Just make sure that doesn't cause an infinite loop.

Comment: You never `return true`. You do the AJAX call, and in the `success` function you check whether the validation was successful and call `form.submit()` to do the real submission.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie lol, sure :P

Comment: just add async: false to the ajax options.

Comment: @Barmer that won't work since the call isn't synchronous :(

Comment: Finished typing... example (trimmed a little) below :)

Comment: @DinoMyte: I wouldn't suggest that.  That could lock-up the browser until the call completes.

Comment: @RocketHazmat :Unfortunately, I don't think there is any other option left to what is needed here. No matter what you return back ( true or false ), the ajax method would return the response before the page can even intercept with the post request.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Why are you getting sentimental ? In my experience, async: false has saved more *sses more times than it has screwed up. If you don't like it thats your perception.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Now where you getting to is completely irrelevant to this thread or anywhere on stackoverflow. And i dont think anybody would be interested in knowing my experience ( perhaps your might be more interesting ). If you wanna get this conversation to get heated up, we can take it somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a sentinel flag outside the scope of the event handler function. You then trigger a submit after setting the flag to allow the submit (I trimmed out all of your code for clarity):

### Simplified cut-down version:

```
var sentinel = false;
$('#sign_up').submit(function (event) {
    // only do the ajax call if a real submit is not in progress
    if (!sentinel) {
        $.ajax({
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // Allow the next submit through
                sentinel = true;
                // generate a submit event (recursive, but only once)
                $('#sign_up').submit()
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
        });
    }
    // return false - cancels original submits until allowed
    // returns true - allows a triggered submit
    return sentinel;
});
```

### Previous example:

```
var sentinel = false;
$('#sign_up').submit(function (event) {
    if (!sentinel) {
        $.ajax({
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // the data.error is not defined so the backend was successful
                if (typeof data.error === 'undefined') {
                    sentinel = true;
                    $('#sign_up').submit()
                }
                // something was wrong at the backend
                else {
                    ("#ajax_error").html(data.message);
                    $('#upload').html('upload File');
                }

            },
            /*
             * Error conecting to the php file, Ajax function failed
             * This event is only called if an error occurred with the request (you can never have both an error and a success callback with a request)
             */
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {},

            // NOTE: This complete code does not appear to be needed
            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                if (textStatus.localeCompare('success') === 0) {
                    sentinel = true;
                    $('#sign_up').submit()
                }

            }
        });
    }
    return sentinel;
});
```

Comment: I think $('#sign_up').submit() will mean infinite loop :(

Comment: @StudentX: You are incorrect... Check the sentinel flag values - it will only allow submit through with a true value once and not hit the Ajax again on that call :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: The submit method would be invoked just once and !sentinel would just execute the ajax request but would return false before it can even recieve response from the request.

Comment: Didn't work, I will get back to this solution later (the original code is quite complex) Till then lets have a look at what else can we do :)

Comment: The basic principal is quite sound and works fine (I use this in production projects all the time). I will remove all the extraneous code so you can see just "the solution"

Comment: No no, not your code, mine is complex so maybe I am missing somthing, please keep it like it is now.

Comment: I get that. I will just strip mine back to the minimum so you can see what it is doing logically. I will leave the original at the end for reference :)

Comment: @DinoMyte: That's fine.  The form submits, the event takes over and runs an AJAX call.  When that AJAX call is done, it will re-trigger the event and let the browser do its thing.

Comment: Simplified version added with comments, so you can see the sequence of events. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have been very kind :) and love the variable naming : "sentinel" :D

Comment: @RocketHazmat : I agree that once response comes back from ajax it would return the appropriate value. However, in case where validation is performed , such approach generally doesn't work because the page finishes up parsing the DOM and no matter what response comes back from ajax, the page is already rendered. Just my 2 cents here.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Sorry bro. Can't spell anything better than that ;)

Comment: @DinoMyte: I'm afraid your comments do not make any sense to me. What parsing is going on in this instance (aside from loading a few panels)? Where could validation come into this and interfere?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Validation was just one of the scenarios where returning the value before the response from ajax would not work. Nothing to do with the context being asked here.

Comment: One question, do we still need "complete" callback ?

Comment: That does appear to be needed in your example. It either succeeds (then checks the result) or fails with an error and does not submit. I took it out of the new example.